# XP: What is automatically deleting folders in C:/Documents and Settings/John/Local Settings/temp?

Tags: windows-xp, temporary-files

In the following location: C:/Documents and Settings/John/Local Settings/temp

If I create any folders, for example I created 5 of them. Within about 5 minutes or less, the folders auto delete. As far as I know there isn't any security software/antivirus running. How can I figure out what is deleting the folders?

There is a program I use that needs a folder in there and just this week, the folder started deleting itself.

To clarify:

1. Within the Temp directory, I right click
2. Choose New Folder
3. Create the folder
4. Wait a few minutes
5. The folder deletes itself.

To verify that it wasn't just the folder my program needed that was being deleted, I created several other folders with random names. They all delete at the same time.

I verified the folders have full permissions for local Administrator, Domain Admins, and the domain user (john) as well. John is also part of the local Admins group.

Everything else on the computer appears to be working fine, except for the folder automatically deleting every few minutes from the temp folder.

Comment: I'll check msconfig now, if I refresh the folders are still there after creating them... but within a few minutes they delete.

Comment: Are you creating these folders programatically or manually(ie, right click -> New folder)?  And did you remove your windows username from the path above or are you making a separate 'Local Settings/temp' folder directly under 'Documents and Settings'?

Comment: @panhandel , I removed my username from the path above. I have edited the post to reflect the exact location. I also am updating the post to address your other question.

Comment: @Damianman Preventing the folders from being cleaned up by some program in that folder may be a losing battle. Folders in there are meant to be cleaned up by running programs. If varying the folder names doesn't help them escape being deleted, you might just make them read-only in the right click properties.

Answer (score 0):

See if the problem persists in safe mode.

Check MSConfig to see what is starting up. Check out the task manager to see what processes are running.

I suspect it's a permissions issue since you're sure it's not another program doing this. Change the permissions on the root folder to give everyone full access (if safe to do so). Meaning ensure C:/Documents and Settings/John/Local Settings/temp has full permission and you own it (you may need to review [taking ownership](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421))

Comment: Which root folder specifically?